# azure kusto join multiple graph/table two one

Tags: kql, kusto-explorer

I try combining the two graphs I have now (working as expected) into one combined to show  In and out. I have used the join command I assume that worked but didn't. did I miss anything?

```
syslog_CL
| where data_s  contains  "out"
| where hostname_s contains "interface"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1hr)  
| summarize Reject=dcount(data_s) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
| project Reject
| join kind = inner (
syslog_CL
| where data_s  contains  "in"
| where hostname_s contains "interface"
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1hr)
| summarize allow=dcount(data_s) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
| project allow
 )
 | order by timestamp asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this instead, using the `dcountif()` aggregation function:

```
syslog_CL
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1hr)  
| where hostname_s contains "interface"
| summarize reject = dcountif(data_s, data_s contains "out"),
            allow = dcountif(data_s, data_s contains "in")
         by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)
| render timechart
```

Comment: The OP seems to be new to KQL, and probably not aware of `make-series`